# Why do $UU^* = I$ and $U^*U = I$ hold on different spaces for the unitary matrix $U$ of a polar decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is from Lang $SL_2$.

Consider the polar decomposition of a matrix A. We let $P_A = (A^*A)^{1/2}$ and set $U$ s.t. we have $$UP_Av = Av.$$

Then, it follows that $U\colon \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im}  A$. Lang now defines $U$ to be $0$ on the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{im} P_A$ and concludes that we have on $\operatorname{im} P_A$ $$U^*U = I,$$ and on $\operatorname{im} A$ we have $$UU^* = I.$$

Questions:

1) To find U, can we take the right inverse of P_A and multiply it on the left by A? The way U was defined here is suggestive that it should not be so simple.

2) Why don't the two equalities hold on the same space? Or how do I see that $UU^*$ is the orthogonal proj. onto im $A$ and $U^*U$ onto im $P_A$?

Comment: If you consider how $U$ acts on the entire space, you see that $U^\ast U$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{Im} P_A$ and $UU^\ast$ the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{Im} A$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $P_A$ is self-adjoint, $(\ker P_A)^\perp = \operatorname{im} P_A$, and so $P_A|_{\operatorname{im}P_A} : \operatorname{im}P_A \to \operatorname{im}P_A$ is invertible, allowing you to define $U : \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} A$ by $$U := A \left(P_A|_{\operatorname{im}P_A}\right)^{-1},$$ where $\left(P_A|_{\operatorname{im}P_A}\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $P_A|_{\operatorname{im}P_A}$ as a map $\operatorname{im}P_A \to \operatorname{im}P_A$. So, you are absolutely right, but you do need to be absolutely precise about domains and codomains.
2. Now, recall that $U : \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} A$, so that $U^\ast : \operatorname{im} A \to \operatorname{im} P_A$. Hence, *a priori*, $$U U^\ast : \operatorname{im} A \to \operatorname{im} A, \quad U^\ast U : \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} P_A.$$ Since $A^\ast A = P_A^2$, it is easy to check by direct computation that $U^\ast U = 1_{\operatorname{im} P_A}$, so that $U : \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} A$ is injective. On the other hand, by the original construction, $U$ is manifestly surjective, i.e., onto $\operatorname{im} A$. Thus, $U : \operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} A$ is necessarily invertible, so that since $U^\ast : \operatorname{im} A \to \operatorname{im} P_A$ is a left inverse of $U$, it is necessarily *the* inverse of $U$, implying $UU^\ast = 1_{\operatorname{im} A}$.

Now, if you extend $U$ to all of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by setting $U|_{(\operatorname{im} P_A)^\perp} := 0$, then you can check directly that $U^\ast|_{(\operatorname{im} A)^\perp} = 0$. This allows you to check, subspace by subspace, that the equalities
$$
 U^\ast U = 1_{\operatorname{im} P_A}, \quad UU^\ast = 1_{\operatorname{im} A}
$$
for $U$ as an operator $\operatorname{im} P_A \to \operatorname{im} A$ translate to the equalities
$$
 U^\ast U = \text{orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{im} P_A$}, \quad U U^\ast = \text{orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{im} A$}
$$
for $U$ as an operator $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$.